# empty html table but with correct number of rows

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have this PDO that fetch rows into html table:

```
      <?php
        $selectAll = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date_now = :date";
        $stmtAll=$conn->prepare($selectAll);
        $stmtAll->bindValue(':date', date("y-m-d"));
        $execAll=$stmtAll->execute();
        $result=$stmtAll->fetchAll();
      ?>
      <?php foreach($result as $rows){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td height="30" align="center"><?php $rows['type'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php $rows['provider'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php $rows['pay'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php $rows['facture'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php $rows['type'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><form action='/architect/pages/delete_row.php' method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="projid" value="" />
          <input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('هل أنت متأكد؟')" name="delete_workers" value="" />
        </form></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>
```

This query should select all rows with current date. I have gotten a table with the correct number of rows but with no data (empty table):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `echo` before each values.

You could either use:

```
<td align="center"><?php echo $rows['provider']; ?></td>
```

Or if you are using PHP 5.4 or later:

```
<td align="center"><?= $rows['provider'] ?></td>
```

Comment: Nevermind, someone else added it as a different answer (Without noting that the option is always available since 5.4, though). Feel free to reject the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You forget to `echo/print` the values.

Replace

```
  <td height="30" align="center"><?php $rows['type'] ?></td>
  <td align="center"><?php $rows['provider'] ?></td>
  <td align="center"><?php $rows['pay'] ?></td>
  <td align="center"><?php $rows['facture'] ?></td>
  <td align="center"><?php $rows['type'] ?></td>
```

with

```
  <td height="30" align="center"><?=$rows['type'] ?></td>
  <td align="center"><?=$rows['provider'] ?></td>
  <td align="center"><?=$rows['pay'] ?></td>
  <td align="center"><?=$rows['facture'] ?></td>
  <td align="center"><?=$rows['type'] ?></td>
```

Note: Short Tags must b enable for above solution. Or alternatively use can replace`<?php $rows` with `<?php echo $rows`